# How to stop grid from collapsing in on itself when browser window is resized?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, resize

I'm creating a website to showcase some of my work and I've run into a problem with the grid collapsing when I resize the browser window to a smaller size.

I'm still very much a noob at coding since I just started learning html and css a week ago, so I can't figure out how to fix it. I've tried various techniques that I've found to similar problems, to no avail. Oh, and I'm using the bootstrap framework if that helps. Here's the html and css codes:

html:

```
<body>

<div class="container">

<!-- Header begin -->

        <div class="row">
            <div id="divider1a" class="span12">divider1a</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div id="divider1b" class="span12">divider1b</div>
        </div>               

        <div class="row">        
            <div id="head" class="span12">   
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="logo" class="span4"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/Logo.png" width="305" height="100" /></a></div>
                    <div id="socialmedia" class="span8"><ul>
                                                            <li><img src="images/rss.png" width="48" height="48" /></li>
                                                            <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=203116454&trk=tab_pro"><img src="images/linkedin.png" width="48" height="48" /></a></li>
                                                            <li><img src="images/vimeo.png" width="48" height="48" /></li>
                                                            <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/burnwesten"><img src="images/youtube.png" width="48" height="48" /></a></li>
                                                        </ul></div>
                    <div id="navbar" class="span8"><ul>
                                                       <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                                                       <li><a href="reel.html">Demo Reel</a></li>
                                                       <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                                                       <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                                                   </ul></div>
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>                

<!-- Header end -->



<!-- Middle begin -->

        <div class="row">
            <div id="divider2a" class="span12">divider2a</div>
        </div>  

        <div class="row">
            <div id="divider2b" class="span12">divider2b</div>
        </div>                  

        <div class="row">
                    <div id="imgbanner" class="span12"><img src="images/imgbanner_comingsoon.png" /></div>    
        </div>    



        <div class="row">            
            <div id="slidebanner" class="span12">        
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="arrowleft" class="span3"><img src="images/arrowleft_comingsoon.png" /></div>  
                    <div id="imgslide" class="span2"><img src="images/imgsquare_comingsoon.png" /></div>
                    <div id="imgslide" class="span2"><img src="images/imgsquare_comingsoon.png" /></div>
                    <div id="imgslide" class="span2"><img src="images/imgsquare_comingsoon.png" /></div>
                    <div id="arrowright" class="span3"><img src="images/arrowright_comingsoon.png" /></div>
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div id="divider3" class="span12">divider3</div>
        </div>            

        <div class="row">
            <div id="welcome-news" class="span12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="welcome" class="span8"><h2>Name</h2>
                                                    <h2>Job title</h2>
                                                    <p>Welcome to my site! 
                                                       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, option fabellas mel et, at has doctus noluisse ullamcorper, no facete probatus evertitur
                                                       vim. Est id mutat lobortis. Cu ius omnesque apeirian interesset. Quo putent consequuntur at. Mel soluta sadipscing 
                                                       te. Ea sed impetus patrioque, sed inani vitae ea, sea ne labore prodesset.

                                                       Nam in ipsum detracto disputando, sea ei habeo aliquam scripserit, vide simul graeco pri eu. Unum possit ea duo, 
                                                       maiorum partiendo has ut. Per tamquam omnesque cu. Sed veniam ancillae luptatum te. Sea repudiare euripidis 
                                                       posidonium ne, ex elit saperet qui.</p></div>
                    <div id="news" class="span4"><h3>Latest News</h3>
                                                 <h4>News Title</h4>
                                                 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, option fabellas mel et, at has doctus noluisse ullamcorper, no facete probatus evertitur
                                                    vim. Est id mutat lobortis. Cu ius omnesque apeirian interesset. Quo putent consequuntur at. Mel soluta sadipscing 
                                                    te. Ea sed impetus patrioque, sed inani vitae ea, sea ne labore prodesset.

                                                    Nam in ipsum detracto disputando, sea ei habeo aliquam scripserit, vide simul graeco pri eu. Unum possit ea duo, 
                                                    maiorum partiendo has ut. Per tamquam omnesque cu. Sed veniam ancillae luptatum te. Sea repudiare euripidis 
                                                    posidonium ne, ex elit saperet qui.</p>
                                                 <p>dd/mm/yy</p></div>
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>

<!-- Middle end -->



<!-- Footer begin -->

        <div class="row">
            <div id="divider4" class="span12">divider4</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div id="copyright" class="span12"><p>Copyright note</p></div>
        </div>

<!-- Footer end -->        

</div> <!-- Container end -->



<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
</body>
```

css:

```
.container { backgound: #28383f;
         margin: 0 auto;
         width: 940px; }                    

#divider1a { background: #051d32;
         height: 10px;
         width: 940px;
         margin-left: 30px ;
         margin-right: 0px ; }

#divider1b { background: #051d32;
         height: 10px;
         width: 940px;
         margin-left: 30px ;
         margin-right: 0px ; }

#logo { background: #28383f;
    color: white;
    height: 105px;
    width: 310px;
    margin-right: 0px; }

#socialmedia { background: #28383f;
           color: white;
           height: 52.5px;
           width: 630px;
           margin-left: 0px; }

#navbar { background: #28383f;
      color: white;
      height: 52.5px;
      width: 630px;
      margin-left: 0px; }

#divider2a { background: #051d32;
         height: 10px;
         width: 940px;
         margin-left: 30px ;
         margin-right: 0px ; }

#divider2b { background: #051d32;
         height: 10px;
         width: 940px;
         margin-left: 30px ;
         margin-right: 0px ; }

#imgbanner { background: #051d32;
         color: white;
         height: 340px;
         width: 940px; 
         margin-left: 30px; }

#slidebanner { background: #051d32;
           height: 190px;
           width: 940px;
           margin-left: 30px;
           margin-right: 0px; }                                  

#arrowleft { background: #051d32;
         color: white;
         height: 190px;
         width: 110px;
         margin-left: 30px;
         margin-right: 0px; }

#arrowright { background: #051d32;
         color: white;
         height: 190px;
         width: 110px;
         margin-right: 0px;
         margin-left: 0px; }

#imgslide { background: #051d32;
        color: white;
        height: 170px;
        width: 170px;
        margin-left: 35px;
        margin-right: 35px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px; }

#divider3 { background: #051d32;
         height: 10px;
         width: 940px;
         margin-left: 30px ;
         margin-right: 0px ; }

#welcome-news { margin-left: 120px;
        margin-left: 30px; }            

#welcome { background: #28383f ;
       color: white;
       height: 500px;
       width: 630px; }

#news { background: #344349; 
    color: white;
    height: 500px;
    width: 310px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 30px; }

#divider4 { background: #051d32;
         height: 10px;
         width: 940px;
         margin-left: 30px ;
         margin-right: 0px ; }      

#copyright { background: #051d32;
      color: white;
      height: 50px;
      width: 940px;
      margin-left: 30px; }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, you might have noticed in the css code that a lot of the divs have a margin-left: 30px; the page doesn't center properly unless those divs have that 30px left margin for some reason. So any help on that topic would help too. Thanks :)

Edit*

Here's what it looks like in the browser at fullscreen:

http://i1051.photobucket.com/albums/s426/AnimationStudent/breakingproblemsfullscreen_zps57543528.png

And this is what happens when I resize the window:

http://i1051.photobucket.com/albums/s426/AnimationStudent/breakingproblemsresized1_zps4a1d66a0.png

Comment: Do you know what is [Responsive Web Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)? TBS is based on RWD.

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle file.Then it will be easy to help you.

Comment: how about you use margin:0 auto; ?

Comment: @PraveenKumar , yes I had heard of it. I'm not really sure how to implement it though.

Comment: @user2388447 Since TBS uses RWD, it uses `@media` queries to change the layout when the viewport size changes.

Comment: @Sreeram , http://jsfiddle.net/browncoat/LB8RZ/1/. As you can see it not only breaks down, but actually collapses on top of itself.

Comment: @bot , yes, I've tried that. Centers it in fullscreen but doesn't solve the breaking problem.

Comment: The fiddle doesn't include Bootstrap. You need to add it to the fiddle or use http://bootply.com instead.

Comment: @user2388447 : The JSFile Is not clear. Have you uploaded this into server.

Answer (score 0):

Good to see you trying to learn a new things. MIght I suggest you view tutorials from places such as [nettuts+](http://net.tutsplus.com/) and a few others as this will deffo help. Also always try to ask questions as that's the only real way you will learn. Now onto your predicament;

Now it seems to me you are trying to establish a static design instead of a responsive design. I assume you want to have it looking the same no matter what screen so try

```
.container { backgound: #28383f;
         margin: 0 auto;
         min-width: 940px; !important}
```

As this with ignore any other sub rulings (even @media ones).

If however you want a responsive design, may I suggest avoid using fixed widths (pixels) and move towards responsive widths(%).

The reason why it might also occur is because your code doest flow. By this I mean you have a span4 and two span8's in the same row. So when the screen shrinks, might be causing the collapsing issue. As regards, to the centring issue...unsure as cannot see a working example so cant tell you why this might be occurring on this design.

Edit*

Based Upon the pictures you have just attached, it seems to be a bit of an unclean and rather cluttered design. By this I mean I do not see the point of the 2 divs and the top or bottom of the header div. Also why are you referring to ids and not classes for styling as on a personal preference I try to avoid using ids as they are better suited towards referencing and classes for styling.

Comment: thanks. I had a feeling the code didn't flow properly and as such was causing the issues. I'll try and fix what you've mentioned and if it's still not working I might just opt for a simpler design.

Comment: I shall try and assist you in a neater approach soon!